# Android can shared preferences be used for login purposes

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have android connected to a MySQL database, the user would login via email and password which is hashed. Each user has a unique ID number. When they successfully login I can transfer their Unique ID to a Shared Preference in private mode to keep track of users. Would something like this work or does it sound to risky? From what I know is that SharedPreferences is the only method that can remember users so they can close and open your app and won't have to login again.

Comment: SharedPreferences should be fine. If you are really concerned about the privacy you could always consider encrypting the unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Shared Preferences is private, remember that rooted users can see any apps' Shared Prefs. Just make sure you don't ever save the password, hashed or not, locally because the hash can always be reversed. It's fine to keep user info, like id and username locally because a bad actor can't really do anything with that. Keeping an access token is the right way to go. If you look at any Shared Prefs of an app with facebook integration you'll see that facebook keeps its token in clear text.

Comment: oh ok that sounds perfect I will look into that. Can a private unique shared preference be stolen by a rooted device? that is my only concern.

Comment: Yep. You can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.testcenter.settingsdebugger&hl=en to peek into other apps. But, like I said, it's find if it's just a token, as that's the purpose of a token, and you can see that facebook does it for apps it integrates with. Storing a password however is a big nono on android.

Answer (score 3):

`SharedPreferences` is the way to go. It is private, belongs to the context of your application and users can't access it.

Comment: But every half decent monkey with a rooted phone can access it.

Comment: I know that, users with rooted devices came to my mind. But this is the most standard way to store even private data. As @Kirk said, he can encrypt his unique id if he wants. But another question comes up - why would user try to stole his own unique id from his own cell phone? If he just needs it in order to know if his app should go to login screen or main screen when it launches, then I think it's perfectly fine like this.

Comment: Oh ok it would not matter if people can see the I.D. because it will only be given once someone successfully logins with the correct email and very long hash password, but even if they can see it can they steal it? and use it as their own? Because then they would be able to post on behalf of users.